# Add Values to Enums in Java with ASM

Tags: java, enums

I need to add a value to an enum and probably the easiest way is gonna be via ASM because I have that already set up.
The class looks like this:

```
public enum Example
{
    TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4
}
```

It needs to look like this:

```
 public enum Example
 {
     TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4, TEST5
 }
```

The current bytecode (extracted with ASM Bytecode Outline) looks like

```
package test;
import java.util.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.*;
public class ExampleDump implements Opcodes {

public static byte[] dump () throws Exception {

ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
FieldVisitor fv;
MethodVisitor mv;
AnnotationVisitor av0;

cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_FINAL + ACC_SUPER + ACC_ENUM, "appeng/api/config/Example", "Ljava/lang/Enum<Lappeng/api/config/Example;>;", "java/lang/Enum", null);

cw.visitSource("Example.java", null);

{
fv = cw.visitField(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_FINAL + ACC_STATIC + ACC_ENUM, "TEST1", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, null);
fv.visitEnd();
}
{
fv = cw.visitField(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_FINAL + ACC_STATIC + ACC_ENUM, "TEST2", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, null);
fv.visitEnd();
}
{
fv = cw.visitField(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_FINAL + ACC_STATIC + ACC_ENUM, "TEST3", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, null);
fv.visitEnd();
}
{
fv = cw.visitField(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_FINAL + ACC_STATIC + ACC_ENUM, "TEST4", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, null);
fv.visitEnd();
}
{
fv = cw.visitField(ACC_PRIVATE + ACC_FINAL + ACC_STATIC + ACC_SYNTHETIC, "$VALUES", "[Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, null);
fv.visitEnd();
}
{
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "values", "()[Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitLineNumber(27, l0);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "$VALUES", "[Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "[Lappeng/api/config/Example;", "clone", "()Ljava/lang/Object;", false);
mv.visitTypeInsn(CHECKCAST, "[Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitInsn(ARETURN);
mv.visitMaxs(1, 0);
mv.visitEnd();
}
{
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "valueOf", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitLineNumber(27, l0);
mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getType("Lappeng/api/config/Example;"));
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/Enum", "valueOf", "(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;", false);
mv.visitTypeInsn(CHECKCAST, "appeng/api/config/Example");
mv.visitInsn(ARETURN);
Label l1 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l1);
mv.visitLocalVariable("name", "Ljava/lang/String;", null, l0, l1, 0);
mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
mv.visitEnd();
}
{
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PRIVATE, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", "()V", null);
mv.visitCode();
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitLineNumber(27, l0);
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 2);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Enum", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", false);
mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
Label l1 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l1);
mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;", null, l0, l1, 0);
mv.visitMaxs(3, 3);
mv.visitEnd();
}
{
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_STATIC, "<clinit>", "()V", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitLineNumber(29, l0);
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "appeng/api/config/Example");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitLdcInsn("TEST1");
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "appeng/api/config/Example", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", false);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST1", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "appeng/api/config/Example");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitLdcInsn("TEST2");
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_1);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "appeng/api/config/Example", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", false);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST2", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "appeng/api/config/Example");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitLdcInsn("TEST3");
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_2);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "appeng/api/config/Example", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", false);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST3", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "appeng/api/config/Example");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitLdcInsn("TEST4");
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_3);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "appeng/api/config/Example", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", false);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST4", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
Label l1 = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(l1);
mv.visitLineNumber(27, l1);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_4);
mv.visitTypeInsn(ANEWARRAY, "appeng/api/config/Example");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST1", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitInsn(AASTORE);
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_1);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST2", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitInsn(AASTORE);
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_2);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST3", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitInsn(AASTORE);
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_3);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "TEST4", "Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitInsn(AASTORE);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTSTATIC, "appeng/api/config/Example", "$VALUES", [Lappeng/api/config/Example;");
mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
mv.visitMaxs(4, 0);
mv.visitEnd();
}
cw.visitEnd();

return cw.toByteArray();
}
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me and knows what I need to do.

Comment: What does it mean to have the same symbol (`TEST3`) appear multiple times in an enum?

Comment: *"I need to add a value to an enum and probably the easiest way is gonna be via ASM because I have that already set up..."* And you don't...have the JDK set up? The easiest way, surely, is to edit the source and compile it.

Comment: Thank you I copied the wrong version of the file correcting it now.

Comment: And if I could I would surely do that, but I need to edit it at runtime, it's complicated to explain but basically I need to edit code of an dependency to add integration for it. It's a minecraft mod if you know what that is.